# Symmetricds syncronization between ms-sql and mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-server, symmetricds

The task is to synchronize data from a ms-sql to a mysql near real-time.

I just found out about symmetricds and I am asking myself if this is possible with symmetricds.

To setup db connections (one ms-sql, one mysql) and synchronize changes on the ms-sql to the mysql near real time?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: Send me a DM on twitter if you have more questions.